# iOS file sharing with SAMBA / CIFS protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i want to access the files from remote system with SAMBA / CIFS , i searched in many ways but i didnt find rpoper solution or documentation on it. Is there any solution please provide me if any example

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to connect with your app files via WiFi .

Basically you need to open a local server within your app.

[CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) may be help you with this issue.

Comment: Thank you, i want to access the files from remote SMB/CIFS server and list them in my iOS device and i need to perform operations like add,edit,delete,streaming is it possible  ?                             EX:https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fileexplorer-free/id510282524?mt=8

Comment: yep it should be possible.

Comment: still it is not clear access network drive is there any other solution

Comment: this is the only way i know, sorry. but it is fair solution.